# How can I translate Self-Service Portal ?

Tags: customer-portal, translation-workbench

I am sure this can be done using Translation workbench, but do not know how to find the setup component that I want to translate. All tabs, buttons, static text need to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

First enable it by Setup - Translation workbench - Translation settings - Activate it.

Assign translators by adding new language and user.

Then you can add translation for setup components by,

Setup - translation workbench - Translate - choose the language - select the setup component - object and double click on the label translation and paste your translated texts there.

Repeat the same for all setup components. For plain text translation use custom labels.

Comment: Thanks Sakthivel. I know about the process but I am not sure which setup component will show up the tab/static text names which we have in self-service portal like "Home", "Log a Support Case", "View Support Cases","Logout", etc. Please let me know if you have any idea about that.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to know how to display the translated content on the portal for standard labels, right? If yes, Depends on the user language the content (all standard components) will render dynamically in the portal. Try to login to the portal user whose language is non English.  Let me know if you still has any issue.